# How do you call the where method in an ActiveRecord abstract class?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, abstract-class

We use database resource tables to provide the values that appear in our application's combo boxes.  Each resource table has a display_name column and a service_name column.  The display name is what the user sees and the service name is sent to the web service.  Some of our fields are optional and I have added an is_default column.  I would like to create an abstract class that returns the default service name.  Here is my first effort.  However, when the CondenserPumpControlType.default_service_name method is called I get:

> Exception message: undefined method `where' for Class:Class Stack
>   trace: ["/apps/ar2/app/models/defaultable_record.rb:5:in`
>   default_service_name'"

I expected the abstract class to invoke CondenserPumpControlType.where and instead it appears to invoke Class.where.  What am I doing wrong.  I can't seem to find much documentation on ActiveRecord abstract classes.

```
class DefaultableRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.default_service_name
    default_value = self.class.where(is_default: 1).first
    default_value.service_name
  end
end

class CondenserPumpControlType < DefaultableRecord
  attr_accessible :display_name, :service_name, :sort_order, :is_default
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.class.where(is_default: 1).first
```

should be

```
self.where(is_default: 1).first
```

Comment: It turns out it could also be: where(is_default: 1).first